# How do I install the beta5 version of PSI4 on my WebMO Basic server?

Tags: software, software-assistance, psi4, windows-operating-system

Installing the basic version of PSI4 on my personal LG Gram 360 (with a Windows OS), used as a my-own WebMO Basic server, was done according to the WebMO tutorial. I then tried to compute the energy of hexaiodostannate(IV) at the wB97X-2(TQZ)/def2-TZVPPD level of theory, a level that is outside of the 45sec CPU time limit of the WebMO demo server- turned out that I needed the beta5 (or at least beta3) version of the package to use said functional.

A quick Google search lead to a precompiled zip file that is supoosed to be "directly usable w.r.t. WebMO"; I don't know what exactly I should do with that file, so I need help.

Comment: +1 but when asking how to install something, it would be helpful to tell us your operating system. For example, if your OS is Fedora, then Psi4 was conveniently packaged by [Susi Lehtola](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/users/142/susi-lehtola), whereas if your OS is Windows, the steps might be slightly different. I'm also having trouble understanding the last sentence: you found something that is "directly" usable, and yet that's where you're stuck? I think elaboration about this is necessary.

Comment: Thanks for now letting us know the operating system, but what exactly do you mean by "I'm stuck at this step"? You have a pre-compiled zip file, and you're stuck at unzipping it?

Comment: What to do with that file

Comment: Have you unzipped the file?

Comment: Yes but there are no instructions on its README.

Comment: Can you point to the source for this zip file?

Comment: https://github.com/psi4/psi4webmo

Comment: All this time you were talking about not knowing what to do with a "file" when in fact it was an entire Git repository containing multiple folders and files? It is almost as if you **wanted** this question to **not** get an answer. Similarly it's taken 4 comments with questions in them in order to get a link to the Git repository (the link should have been in the original question). I've now tried to search "beta5 version of psi4" and the first suggestion on Google is this exact question. Took a while to find [this](https://psicode.org/posts/beta5/) which says it's from 2013 (git repo: 2019).

Comment: From the WebMO support [page](https://www.webmo.net/support/binaries_linux.html#psi4), you can get how to install and run Psi4 with WebMO.

Comment: @Camps the support page does not tell me how to install the BETA version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I then tried to compute the energy of hexaiodostannate(IV) at the wB97X-2(TQZ)/def2-TZVPPD level of theory

wB97X-2(TQZ), published by Chai and Head-Gordon in [doi:10.1063/1.3244209](https://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.3244209) is a double hybrid functional. The list of double hybrids available in Psi4 is given at

https://psicode.org/psi4manual/master/dft_byfunctional.html#double-hybrid

and wB97X-2(TQZ) is not on the list. A quick google search suggests that only Q-Chem (who Chai and Head-Gordon are coauthors of) implements this functional, see

https://manual.q-chem.com/latest/sect_DFTexchangecorrelation.html

Q-Chem can be used with WebMO (see installation instructions [here](https://www.webmo.net/support/binaries_linux.html#qchem)] but it is commercial software and you need to pay $$$ for a license.

> turned out that I needed the beta5 (or at least beta3) version of the package to use said functional

That is not a version. Which version do you think you need? Where is it said that Psi4 has that functional?

> A quick Google search lead to a precompiled zip file that is supoosed to be "directly usable w.r.t. WebMO"; I don't know what exactly I should do with that file, so I need help.

As instructed by Campos in the comments above, you need to look at the WebMO installation instructions at https://www.webmo.net/support/binaries_linux.html#psi4